# "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer" while raising an exception

Tags: python, unicode, python-requests, python-unicode

I'm facing some weird exception on the production system:

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, InvalidHTTPStatusCode found

But I can't reproduce it locally. Also when I log into the production system and try to manually reproduce the error everything works OK.

**Code**:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
_session = requests.Session()

class HTTPResponseException(HTTPError):
  def __init__(self, response):
    self.response = response

  def __str__(self):
    return 'HTTP request failed with status code {}.\n' \
           'URL {}\nContent {}\nHeaders {}'.format(
               self.response.status_code,
               self.response.url,
               self.response.content,
               self.response.headers)


class InvalidHTTPStatusCode(HTTPResponseException):
  pass


def get_request(url)
  response = _session.request('get', url)
  if response.status_code != 200
    ex = InvalidHTTPStatusCode(response)
    raise ex

get_request('https://my.server.com/REST/something')
```

**Stacktrace** (tried to simplify it):

```
File '/my_request.py', line x, in get_request", 
   raise ex", 
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, InvalidHTTPStatusCode found",
```

**Server response**:

The error response from the web service is HTTP 401 and the body is some HTML code containing the Unicode char "×".

**My question**:

I currently have no clue why `raise ex` can cause this `coercing to Unicode` exception. I have no Unicode value in this line. I somehow think that there is some serialization ongoing in the depths of Python that will cause this exception (due to the Unicode char within `response.content`) but that's just a guess.

Do you know the real reason and how I can fix that issue?

**Enviroment**:

- Ubuntu 14.04.3
- Python 2.7.9 (self compiled to a separate directory)
- requests 2.5.3

Comment: Is the production environment using Python 3 by any chance? (A lot of encoding issues can pop up between switching versions)

Comment: No, it's 2.7.9. We basically create a virtualenv from the self compiled 2.7.9 and then run the Python script in that virtual environment. Also I validated the version already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mean time I changed the implementation exception to the following code which seems to resolve the issue with **Unicode** chars in the response:

```
class HTTPResponseException(HTTPError):

    def __init__(self, response):
        self.response = response


    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')


    def __unicode__(self):
        msg = u'HTTP request failed with status code {}.\nURL {}\nContent {}\nHeaders {}'.format(
            self.response.status_code,
            self.response.url,
            self.response.text,
            self.response.headers)
        return msg
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you're raising InvalidHTTPStatusCode. This inherits from HTTPResponseException. This has a __ str__ method that formats a non-unicode string with the returned data.

In short,

```
    return u'HTTP request failed with status code {}.\n' \
           'URL {}\nContent {}\nHeaders {}'.format(
    ....
```

(Add u to the start of the string.) The reason you are having trouble reproducing it is likely because the logging calls this function, while you aren't. I bet you can get a similar exception if you explicitly call this.

Comment: I tried to call str(ex) basically. Also I invoked __str__ directly. No problem. Also the __str__ method must return a string of type str. If I would prefix it with u then it's of type unicode and therefore not valid anymore. What I could try is to prefix it with u and then encode it to utf-8 so that I have a str string again.

Comment: I will try today whether the logging library does something with my code.